# An alternative to "something clicked in place"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

As per the title, I'm looking for a shorter expression that has generally the same meaning as "something clicked".

Closest one I could think of was something like "enlightened", but that isn't too fitting for my needs, which is something like:

> He was befuddled until he saw the instruction sheet, at which point everything *clicked into place*.

Comment: Just _clicked_ is fine.

Comment: Agreed. Based on the title, I thought you were looking for something like "seated" (as in "fit into position").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of metaphorical possibilities:

**The light dawned**.  From [*The Bonevski Legacy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=yY-62QG6BDAC&pg=PA109&dq=%22the%20light%20dawned%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUoMq1_vPJAhXE4D4KHb9HAZYQ6AEIUzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22the%20light%20dawned%22&f=false) by F Duerden:

> Mo looked confused, "I'm sorry, you're
>   the?
>       "Locum, the stand in for
>   Reverend Meeches.  I understand from the bishop may be absent from his
>   duties today."
>       Suddenly **the light
>   dawned** for Mo.  "So that's why there was no answer at the vicarage
>   this morning.

**Fell into place**. From [*Encounters:  People of Asian Descent in the Americas*](https://books.google.com/books?id=bkFFnHqy04cC&pg=PA49&dq=%22everything%20fell%20into%20place%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKu9T8__PJAhVJWj4KHXm-CJY4HhDoAQgzMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22everything%20fell%20into%20place%22&f=false) by R Rustomji-Kerns:

> It was the way in which those words were spoken or heard that embodied
>   the spirit of my father and all his peculiarities. In that moment of
>   revelation everything **fell into place**. It finally made sense to me
>   why my father used to address strangers as "my friend."

**Crystalized**. From *[Assassin on Stage: Brutus, Hamlet, and the Death of Lincoln](https://books.google.com/books?id=Y5JlAAAAMAAJ&q=%22suddenly%20crystalized%22&dq=%22suddenly%20crystalized%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjj1qTXgPTJAhXB4D4KHfwzBJUQ6AEIRjAH)* by A Furtwangler

> For him, as for Clarke, Booth's performances were a revelation; they
>   suddenly **crystalized** the meaning of all poetry and drama and left
>   a lifelong impression.

**The fog cleared**.  From [*Don't Look Back: (Lily's Story, Book 2)*](https://books.google.com/books?id=xi4UAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT226&lpg=PT226&dq=%22fog%20cleared%20from%20my%20mind%22&source=bl&ots=kqVdceIfju&sig=RfRPZW4OImk0u3S3Y1FtkUfbMMs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8kIHChPTJAhUBFj4KHdAvCpUQ6AEIJDAD#v=onepage&q=%22fog%20cleared%20from%20my%20mind%22&f=false) by C Kersey

> I was still by the back door where I had fallen, but Greta had stopped
>   barking.  At first I was groggy an couldn't remember exactly what had
>   happened, but as **the fog cleared** from my mind, it all came back to
>   me in stunning detail.

Answer (score 2):

My favourite idiom for this is: **[the penny dropped](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=the%20penny%20dropped%20definition)**

> used to indicate that someone has finally realized or understood something

This saves you an entire word: you replace "everything clicked into place" with "the penny dropped".

Answer (score 1):

You could also use "made sense" in this context, although it is not that much shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Consider,

*everything became **crystal clear***.

> crystal clear: very easy to understand [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/crystal-clear)

*the fog **lifted** from his mind*

> lift:  to move upward and disappear or become scattered *The haze lifted.* [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lift)